# Resolve an array of floats in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, github-api, graphql-js, scalar

How does one return a set of scalar values from an array in GraphQL? Everything else can be mapped with a key but unsure how to resolve the following: `all: [23,45,7,4]`

elsewhere retrieving data:

```
  axios.get(`${mostStarredRepoUrl}/stats/participation`)
       .then((p) => {
         console.log(p.data) // {all: [23,45,7,4,..etc..], owner: [0,0,0,..etc..]}
         return p.data;
```

GraphQL custom object file

```
  module.exports = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'GithubParticipations',

    fields: () => ({
      all: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLFloat) },
      owner: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLFloat) }
    }),
  });
```

in /graphiql, I get `activity: null` in the results from `query { activity { all } }`. Yet in the docs side tab, when i burrow down through my custom types, i get `all: [Float]`

Comment: Did you try to use `resolve` in all {}? you should be able to see the value --> all{ resolve: body=> console.log(body)}

Comment: already tried, doesnt log anything

Comment: Can you include the schema for your `activity` query?